# Suspension from one chat has suspended me from this chat. How can that be?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

**First**, I was suspended for a year from the X site. And I have appealed it.

**Then,** (several days later) I was having a discussion with a moderator in the French chat, which I thought was in depth and going along fine in terms of questions I have, and boom, **someone, a mod, suspended me without warning just as we were talking!** [re editing: there was nothing untoward in my sentence. The whole point of this post is explained here. Please do not edit it. I had no way of **knowing** who suspended me. I did not know it was possible for another mod to suspend me while I was talking to a different mod.]

Now, I tried to access the chat here on ELU, and it says I cannot as I have been suspended from chat. Is this a bug or what?

(By the way, please don't use jargon-y language here. I won't understand it. Thanks.)

For the information of any French forum users: This question is about being suspended from chatting while speaking to a moderator on the French site. This could have happened anywhere as I am told this is a site-wide suspension. I was merely explaining what happened.

I repeat: **Since chat suspensions are site-wide, there is no way to know who initiated the suspension or where, ergo, one can ask about this anywhere.** And FLE participants should stop maligning me for asking a simple question. **I am not blaming the mod with whom I was having the discussion when another mod did this.** It was just shocking to me that another mod would do that when a person (me) was talking to a mod. **And no one has yet addressed this issue specifically.**

Please note once again: This is not about the site where this happened. This is a general question so I would appreciate it if those who keep ascribing intentions to me would just stop it.

Comment: You can't know who suspended you (unless they told you). Any moderator on any SE site has moderator powers in chat, and many in fact exercise those powers in chatrooms other than those of their mod site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I highly doubt another mod other than the one I was conversing with suspended me from the chat. As that would mean that the suspending mod would be cutting off the communication being engaged in a colleague. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Randal'Thor maybe you can elaborate on how suspension from Q&A and from chat and over different sites interact?

Comment: Flags on a chat message can be handled by any mod in the network. That includes chat bans.

Comment: This happened to me once before and I had to complain. Being suspended from one chat does not suspend you from all. And my chatting privileges were restored on the other sites. Now, it has happened again.

Comment: @Tsundoku I beg you, we were the ones just chatting. You and I were chatting and all of a sudden my chat privileges in the French chat were cut off in mid sentence. Did you suspend me? And if so, did you realize that suspended me too?

Comment: @Lambie no, wrong, the system is by-designed to block someone who's chat suspended from talking across chat.stackexchange.com.  If you received a chat suspension, you probably did something wrong, but should be posting on the relevant site's meta feed and not some random unaffiliated site's meta feed.  (mods: you might want to [meta-tag:by-design] this post)

Comment: I was listening to you and waiting for your next response. I am not at liberty to tell you who implemented the chat ban.

Comment: @ThomasWard I did something wrong while chatting??

Comment: @Tsundoku You don't have to tell me who it was. That means that you too were caught off guard then.

Comment: @Lambie Being suspended from one chat does suspend you from all. You can be temporarily kicked from a single room (that's not what happened here), but chat *suspensions* apply to the entire chat.SE server. A main-site suspension on one site will lead to a chat suspension iff that site is your "chat parent" (which wasn't the case for you). Otherwise, main-site suspensions and chat suspensions are largely independent, although it's *discouraged* to use chatrooms of X site while suspended on that site.

Comment: @ThomasWard I am posting here because this is not random. I had also been having a conversation here and am banned here to. I don't see how the French meta site is going to help me with the chat suspension here.

Comment: @Lambie I have no insight into what happened in chat, as I said in my answer, I was watching a list of new questions posted to SE because I was just bored and doing that, and decided to weigh in on the reply to your post - nothing more.  I have no insights into what specifically was going on at the time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor So, I can't chat here either? Is that right?

Comment: @Lambie yes, because of the way the chat systems are configured, and that you were chat-banned on the French rooms which is part of chat.stackexchange.com, you're chat-suspended from English Language and Usage rooms and **any other StackExchange site's chat rooms as well.**  Given you have a live appeal for a ban on a site at the CMs level you should focus entirely patience and waiting for the CMs to rule on the issue.  Any further complaining like this is likely to not help you in the grand scheme of the review.

Comment: Please do not tell me not to complain. I am merely trying to understand what's going on. And I still do not get it. It's very weird to be suddenly cut off from chatting **with an actual moderator** when you are. Another moderator did that to the one chatting with me?

Comment: I'm locking this post so the comments don't get more out of hand. While we can explain how the chat software works, the chat suspension itself has nothing to do with ELU, so there's not much more to be said here.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure what "this issue" is that you refer to in your new last sentence. But I **am** sure that it has nothing to do with this site. If you are asking about mechanics, mods are presented with flags but without context and it is perfectly possible to suspend without knowing you were chatting with another mod. But since no-one knows who did that, there **is nothing more to be said here.** We have explained how you are suspended from chat on ELU. We certainly can't do anything about what was happening on another site's chat.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ok, I have understood re site-wide or cross-site suspension. When I said "this issue" I was referring to the fact of chatting with one mod while being suspended by another. That is really kind of odd. How does that make the mod with whom I was chatting feel? For those of us who are not IT nerds, things around here can get quite confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chat suspensions are server wide. If you have a chat suspension on chat.stackexchange.com it covers *all the rooms* on the server, regardless of what site the room is associated/parented with. There's no option to suspend someone 'only' on a specific site's chatroom or a specific chatroom

> he suspended me without warning just as we were talking!

Well not necessarily. Chat flags go to any moderator on the chat for moderator attention flags, and some flags go to 10k users. It could be any moderator, and it seems unlikely that a moderator just decided to suspend you mid conversation without warning.

Basically its likely to be *any other moderator* active at the time.

That said, considering the circumstances - and looking at the situation, complaining about a suspension on the chat of the site you were suspended *while* your suspension is in review feels ... potentially problematic, it might have been wise to wait for the review to complete.

Comment: I was **talking to a moderator**. I was suspended. I had no way of knowing but could only guess. And I guessed WRONG. Right. But how can there be a chat flag when you are talking with a moderator?? I don't get it. I am NOT complaining.

Comment: @Lambie Not everything on SE is synched up in real time.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a diamond moderator from another site, the only reason I'm responding is because I saw this post in the live feed of posts I was watching and decided to respond.  (I have no knowledge of why or who suspended you in chat, and have no insights into what happened there, I'm just responding to your post is all)

The Chat system for all StackExchange sites (except for Meta SE and StackOverflow) is all interlinked.  That is, if you receive a chat suspension on French language chat, that chat suspension applies across all of chat.stackexchange.com, which means it applies to the ELU chat page as well.

This is not a bug, this is by-design and has been that way since the Dawn of the chat.

There's no way to ID who suspended you or why, any diamond moderator on one of the Stack Exchange sites has the ability to squash you in chat across chat.stackexchange.com.

It's also not a good idea to whine/complain about a site suspension and/or chat ban when it's under review, so that's probably something to consider - your behavior "looks bad" when you do this, and it likely will affect the review of your chat ban/suspension if one's underway.

**Note that this has nothing to do with English Language and Usage, though, so you probably posted this in the wrong meta/site.**

Comment: What a weird rule. So, you are suspended from all chats, but not suspended from all sites.  **I am not complaining. I am trying to understand what was going on**.

Comment: Chat suspensions are chat server wide (chat.stackexchange.com).  Site suspensions are on an individual site level unless you've done something so egregious that you've earned a smackdown from the CMs at a network-wide level (and if you get THAT, you're suspended **everywhere**)

Comment: I have to say the chat being server wide seems really dumb to me. This is the right meta site since any site with chat would be the right one to ask this question on as the suspension applies to all of them. How can one be right and another wrong? :)

Answer (score 9):

I've actually been in a similar situation to you, many years ago. The relation between main sites and chat, especially in regard to suspensions, can be frustrating sometimes. So I sympathise with your situation. Let me try to explain so that you have a clearer understanding of what's going on.

A few things to understand about the nature of chat suspensions, as far as system technicalities go:

- Chat suspensions cannot be done per-room or per-site. You can be temporarily kicked from a single room, but only for a maximum of 30 minutes. Chat suspensions apply to the entire chat.SE server.
- A main-site suspension on X.stackexchange.com will lead to a chat suspension iff that site is your "chat parent" (you can set your "parent site" to be any main site where you have an account). Otherwise, main-site suspensions and chat suspensions are largely independent.
- Chat suspensions can also be applied manually by moderators. Any moderator on any SE site has moderator powers in chat, and many in fact exercise those powers in chatrooms other than those of their mod site.
- (If you're already suspended on chat, changing your parent site won't lift the suspension. It's possible for a moderator to sneakily suspend you by changing your parent site to the site where you're suspended and refreshing your chat profile so that the suspension propagates to chat, but I consider this inappropriate.)

Another important thing, which is **NOT** in-built to the system, is that you're generally *discouraged* from using the chatrooms of X.stackexchange.com while suspended on that site. As this rule is not system-enforced, users who are suspended on one site may be expected to keep out of that site's chatrooms (they may keep using the chatrooms of sites they're not suspended on) or risk losing their access to all of chat. As chat is moderated by 600-odd moderators from the entire SE network with widely varying moderation styles, this rule is very inconsistently enforced.

So, how does all of this apply to your case?

- Your chat suspension was applied manually by a moderator, specifically for chat and not associated with your French.SE suspension.
- As you may have surmised from the response to this meta post, a number of moderators from across the network are at least vaguely aware of you in chat. It would be unwise to assume you know who suspended you. (It wasn't me, by the way. We've never met, and I don't know what you did to get suspended. I just saw this meta post and thought I could help.)
- It can be dangerous to use the chatrooms associated to a site where you're suspended. Clearly at least one French.SE moderator was OK with it, but maybe someone else wasn't. (Chat has inconsistent moderation, unfortunately.)
- Obviously, chat suspensions can also be specifically for bad behaviour in chat, rather than just for using rooms you shouldn't be using. A long chat suspension is likely to be based on a pattern of bad behaviour rather than one or two recent problematic posts. Unfortunately, chat suspensions aren't accompanied by mod messages to tell you what you did wrong. (Again, I don't know you and don't know why this particular suspension was applied.)
- You may have a chance of appealing this chat suspension, if you're active on other sites (where you're not suspended) and wish to use their chatrooms. It worked for me, many years ago. However, any unsuspension from chat is likely to be conditional on you not using the chatrooms of French.SE.

Comment: Thank you for responding to me with patience and no moralizing. I am going out to take a break as I am slightly miffed with this site. I will return and read your answer carefully at it look like one I might actually be able to understand. Again, thanks.

Comment: Rand, here's the odd part. I was actually chatting with a mod when this happened. That means that whoever did it knew that, I presume.. I cannot believe the meanness of spirit around here. Four downvotes? Anyway, you can see by that last deleted post how contentious some people are.